# How do I make code send all the output into a single CMD window?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a simple Java client & server pair (here called  `FixedMessageSequenceClient` and `FixedMessageSequenceServer`). I want the output from both of them to go to the same CMD window. However, as it is they go to separate Windows. Here is my code so far:

```
$serviceStart = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$serviceStart.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$serviceStart.UseShellExecute = $false; #needed to redirect console input
#$serviceStart.FileName = ""
$serviceStart = Start-Process java  FixedMessageSequenceServer 
$serviceStart.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Java_Scratch2\FixedMessageSequenceServer.java"

$serviceStart.Arguments = "AsConsole"

$serviceStart = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($serviceStart)

$service2Start = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$service2Start.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$service2Start.UseShellExecute = $false #needed to redirect console input
#$service2Start.FileName
$service2Start = Start-Process java  FixedMessageSequenceClient
$service2Start.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Java_Scratch2\FixedMessageSequenceClient.java"

$service2Start.Arguments = "AsConsole" 

$service2Start = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($service2Start)

#$JavaServer = Start-Process java FixedMessageSequenceClient
```

I thought that the line

```
$service2Start.RedirectStandardInput = $true
```

would force the output to go to one CMD window.

Answer (score 2):

Start both processes as [background jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and fetch the jobs' output periodically:

```
$server = Start-Job -Name 'fmsserver' -ScriptBlock {
  Set-Location 'C:\Java_Scratch2\FixedMessageSequenceServer.java'
  & java FixedMessageSequenceServer AsConsole
}
$client = Start-Job -Name 'fmsclient' -ScriptBlock {
  Set-Location 'C:\Java_Scratch2\FixedMessageSequenceClient.java'
  & java FixedMessageSequenceClient AsConsole
}

while ($server.State, $client.State -contains 'running') {
  if ($server.HasMoreData) { Receive-Job $server }
  if ($client.HasMoreData) { Receive-Job $client }
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}

# fetch remaining output after completion
Receive-Job $server
Receive-Job $client

# clean up
Remove-Job $server
Remove-Job $client
```

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure I'm understanding how to code this one.  When I put the client and server code within `- ScriptBlock` then I get  error saying  `"Property 'WorkingDirectory' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists
 and is settable.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (WorkingDirectory:String) [],
   RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Property 'Arguments' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is
 settable."` Thanks alot

Comment: @Coffee You're using `Start-Process` without `-PassThru`, so it doesn't return the created ProcessInfo object, leaving the variable empty. But even if it didn't, the object wouldn't have a property `WorkingDirectory` in the first place, as you're replacing the ProcessStartInfo object you created before. You're mixing different process creation methods there (`Start-Process` vs. `[Diagnostics.Process]::Start()`). And you don't need either of them anyway. Just change the working directory via `Set-Location` and start the processes with the call operator (`&`) inside the script blocks.